# How to find First and last item in each loop specific in if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add a new div on First and last item in loop. Which we can easily get through jQuery function length. But in my Scenario I need to only get the First and Last item if we are on specific condition.

I am getting the Object from the API and based the key value I need to find that how many specific value are on the key and then add New Div on First and Last Items.

I want to Append New div when first time on Hidden Condition and on Last time. Is there any way to add it?

```
$.each(obj.dynamicList, function(i, v){
    //console.log(i);
    var label    = v['label'];
    var name     = v['id'];
    var value    = v['value'];
    var required = v['required'];
    var type     = v['type'];
    var list     = v['list'];

    if(v['type'] == "Input" && v['id'] == "email" ){
        $('#part3_append_form').append("<div class='form-group'><label class='ssjob-label'>"+ label +"</label><input type='email' class='form-control' "+ (required == 'Y' ? 'required': '') + "  id='"+ name +"' name='"+ name +"' value='"+ email +"'></div>");
    
    }else if( v['type'] == "Hidden"){

      $('#part3_append_form').append("<input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='"+ name +"' value='"+ value +"'>");
    
    }else{
        $('#part3_append_form').append("<div class='form-group'><label class='ssjob-label'>"+ label +"</label><input type='text' "+ (required == 'Y' ? 'required': '') + " class='form-control' id='"+ name +"' name='"+ name +"' value='"+ value +"'></div>");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can catch hiddenType objects with filter.

```
  var examplObj= [
    {
      label: "obj 00",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "type",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 01",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "type",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 02",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "Hidden",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 03",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "type",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 04",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "Hidden",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 05",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "Hidden",
      list: "list",
    },
    {
      label: "obj 06",
      name: "id",
      value: "value",
      required: "required",
      type: "type",
      list: "list",
    },
  ];

  var filtered = examplObj.filter((t) => t.type == "Hidden");
  var firstHidden = filtered[0]; // first time
  var lastHidden = filtered[filtered.length - 1]; // last time
```